# iOS7 MPMoviePlayerController not showing minimise button on tool bar of player (the bar with play pause buttons)

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

Implementing MPMoviePlayerController on iOS7 does not show a minimise button on toolbar as it was showing with iOS6.

This is required for a requirement where I want to minimise the video from full screen to normal screen without pausing or stopping the video. I can add a custom button to video layout, but i cannot hide or show it, to be in sync with the toolbar while video is playing.

Please give me some suggestions for achieving this.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "minimize button" as there is no such thing from my understanding. Would you care to add a screenshot of the element in question? I can only guess that you are referring to a function that is commonly triggered by the pinch gesture on the player window...

Comment: By minimize I mean getting back in playback mode to normal size from full screen. It was a small icon right over play button till iOS6.